# Celery with broker and result backend using MongoDB with multi ip

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, pymongo

I am using mongodb as my celery broker and result backend. With single node configuration it works fine. But I want to run it with multi ip support like I mentioned below

```
"CELERY_BROKER_URL":"mongodb://x.x.x.x:zzz,y.y.y.y:zzz/CELERY_BROKER?replicaSet=rs0"
"CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND":"mongodb://x.x.x.x:zzz,y.y.y.y:zzz/CELERY_RESULT?replicaSet=rs0"
```

The above config would throw :

> ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as **zzz,y.y.y.y:zzz**

Does celery support multi ip connections?

Are there any workaround for achieving this.

Comment: I doubt. The code that handles parsing MongoDB URL is 10 years old. (It is in kombu/transport/mongodb)